# Add a sub-array into an object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object

I have this array of objects:

```
    myList = [
        { name: 'line', icon:'line-chart' },
        { name : 'spline', icon: 'spline-chart' },
        { name : 'bar', icon: 'bar-chart' }
    ];
```

Each of these objects represents a button. When that button is clicked it should activate that type of chart.

Another functionality that I must create is that each of these buttons when it is clicked, it activates (or deactivates) other buttons.

For example, `line` button must activate 3 other buttons while, `spline` and `bar` must activate only one each.

```
line - single, double, triple
spline - single
bar - triple
```

The set of secondary buttons is this:

```
    mySecondList = [
        { name: 'Single', icon:'a' },
        { name : 'Double', icon: 'b' },
        { name : 'Triple', icon: 'c' }
    ];
```

My problem comes here when I want to make a connection between these two.

I tried to incorporate the second array into the first one like this:

```
myList = [
    { name: 'line', icon:'line-chart', [{ name: 'Single', icon:'a' }, { name : 'Double', icon: 'b' }, { name : 'Triple', icon: 'c' }] },

    { name : 'spline', icon: 'spline-chart', [{ name: 'Single', icon:'a' }] },

    { name : 'bar', icon: 'bar-chart', [{ name: 'Single', icon:'a' }] }
];
```

but it seems it's not the correct way.

Any suggestions?

Comment: you can't do this without param

Comment: You have to make a object key to assign an array to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a name to the array. Use something like this:

```
var myList = [
    { name: 'line', icon:'line-chart', arr: [{ name: 'Single', icon:'a' }, { name : 'Double', icon: 'b' }, { name : 'Triple', icon: 'c' }] },

    { name : 'spline', icon: 'spline-chart', arr: [{ name: 'Single', icon:'a' }] },

    { name : 'bar', icon: 'bar-chart', arr: [{ name: 'Single', icon:'a' }] }
];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't just add a value to an object, you need to comply to the key-value format.

Meaning:

```js
{ name : 'spline', icon: 'spline-chart', FIELD_NAME: [{ name: 'Single', icon:'a' }] }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Wrong**

```
myList = [
{ name: 'line', icon:'line-chart', [{ name: 'Single', icon:'a' }, { name : 'Double', icon: 'b' }, { name : 'Triple', icon: 'c' }] }
];
```

> you can't insert `array` in `object` without put `param`

**Right**

```
myList = [
{ name: 'line', icon:'line-chart', data: [{ name: 'Single', icon:'a' }, { name : 'Double', icon: 'b' }, { name : 'Triple', icon: 'c' }] }
];
```

There you have `data` param as `array` which you can put `objects` on it

```
myList[0].data.push({ name : 'Triple', icon: 'c' });
```

`[0]` mean first `object` in `myList`

Answer (score 1):

The inner element of "myList" list are objects, and as object every attribute need a name so the array that u try to add can't me added cause of the missing name...
the correct code should be:

```
myList = [
    { name: 'line', icon:'line-chart', myArray:[{ name: 'Single', icon:'a' }, { name : 'Double', icon: 'b' }, { name : 'Triple', icon: 'c' }] },

    { name : 'spline', icon: 'spline-chart', myArray:[{ name: 'Single', icon:'a' }] },

    { name : 'bar', icon: 'bar-chart', myArray:[{ name: 'Single', icon:'a' }] } 

];
```